# Upgrade python 2 to python 3.8.8 in SUSElinux and install pip3

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, suse

I have python 2.9 on my suse-linux machine.

`(SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP1)`

I have upgraded it to python 3.8.8.

When I am trying to install pip using

`zypper install python3-pip`

It says, python3-pip not found.

I am afraid if python3 is not installed properly,

Have run `python3.8 -m test`, I see some error

`AttributeError: module 'posix' has no attribute '_all_'`

`During handling above exception, another exception occured:`

`SystemError: <built-in function dir> returned NULL without setting an error.`

Have seen quite a few questions in Stackoverflow, nothing really helped.

Could someone help me fix this?

Edit (How I installed 3.8.8 - as root user):

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.8/Python-3.8.8.tgz

tar -xvzf Python-3.8.8.tgz

cd Python-3.8.8

./configure

make

make install

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: How do you install Python 3.8 on Suse12. Python3.8 is only available for Suse15, isn't it?

Comment: Is it? Am not too sure.. Added the commands I used to install as edit to the question

Comment: If you compile Python, you can't use zypper to install package.

Comment: You mean? Could you please elaborate..

Comment: Maybe you should post the same question to https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Will do. Thanks

Comment: Try to recompile with an older version of Python like 3.4 to check if it works. As far I know, Python 3.3 is available as package in SuSe 12.